# Why are those 3 loops faster than 1 short lapply

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, microbenchmark

While trying to optimize and benchmark a function, I was able to shrink 3 for loops into 1 short `lapply` call, but the function got slower.

I am trying to understand why that happens, as with the 3 loops I preallocate 3 lists with the same length and fill them in 3 different loops, which doesnt seem necessary and inefficient.

```
## Data #################
Grid = structure(list(ID = 1:81, X = c(99.99922283, 299.99922281, 499.9992228, 
                                       699.99922279, 899.99922277, 1099.99922275, 1299.99922274, 1499.99922273, 
                                       1699.99922271, 99.99922293, 299.99922291, 499.99922291, 699.99922289, 
                                       899.99922287, 1099.99922286, 1299.99922284, 1499.99922283, 1699.99922282, 
                                       99.99922303, 299.99922302, 499.99922301, 699.999223, 899.99922298, 
                                       1099.99922296, 1299.99922295, 1499.99922294, 1699.99922292, 99.99922314, 
                                       299.99922312, 499.99922311, 699.9992231, 899.99922308, 1099.99922307, 
                                       1299.99922306, 1499.99922304, 1699.99922303, 99.99922324, 299.99922323, 
                                       499.99922322, 699.9992232, 899.99922319, 1099.99922317, 1299.99922316, 
                                       1499.99922315, 1699.99922313, 99.99922335, 299.99922333, 499.99922332, 
                                       699.99922331, 899.9992233, 1099.99922328, 1299.99922327, 1499.99922325, 
                                       1699.99922324, 99.99922345, 299.99922344, 499.99922342, 699.99922341, 
                                       899.9992234, 1099.99922338, 1299.99922337, 1499.99922335, 1699.99922334, 
                                       99.99922356, 299.99922354, 499.99922353, 699.99922352, 899.9992235, 
                                       1099.99922348, 1299.99922347, 1499.99922345, 1699.99922344, 99.99922367, 
                                       299.99922365, 499.99922364, 699.99922362, 899.99922361, 1099.99922359, 
                                       1299.99922358, 1499.99922356, 1699.99922355), Y = c(1699.9975638, 
                                                                                           1699.99756369, 1699.99756357, 1699.99756347, 1699.99756336, 1699.99756325, 
                                                                                           1699.99756314, 1699.99756303, 1699.99756292, 1499.99756399, 1499.99756388, 
                                                                                           1499.99756377, 1499.99756366, 1499.99756355, 1499.99756344, 1499.99756333, 
                                                                                           1499.99756322, 1499.99756311, 1299.99756418, 1299.99756408, 1299.99756396, 
                                                                                           1299.99756386, 1299.99756375, 1299.99756363, 1299.99756353, 1299.99756342, 
                                                                                           1299.99756331, 1099.99756438, 1099.99756427, 1099.99756416, 1099.99756405, 
                                                                                           1099.99756394, 1099.99756384, 1099.99756372, 1099.99756361, 1099.99756351, 
                                                                                           899.99756457, 899.99756446, 899.99756434, 899.99756424, 899.99756414, 
                                                                                           899.99756403, 899.99756392, 899.99756381, 899.9975637, 699.99756477, 
                                                                                           699.99756466, 699.99756454, 699.99756443, 699.99756433, 699.99756422, 
                                                                                           699.99756411, 699.99756401, 699.99756389, 499.99756496, 499.99756485, 
                                                                                           499.99756474, 499.99756463, 499.99756452, 499.99756441, 499.9975643, 
                                                                                           499.9975642, 499.99756409, 299.99756516, 299.99756505, 299.99756494, 
                                                                                           299.99756483, 299.99756472, 299.99756461, 299.9975645, 299.99756439, 
                                                                                           299.99756428, 99.99756535, 99.99756524, 99.99756513, 99.99756502, 
                                                                                           99.99756491, 99.9975648, 99.99756469, 99.99756458, 99.99756448
                                       )), row.names = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
                                                         "19", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "31", 
                                                         "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "41", "42", "43", 
                                                         "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", 
                                                         "56", "57", "58", "59", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
                                                         "68", "69", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
                                                         "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "91", "92", 
                                                         "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"), class = "data.frame")

mut2 = sapply(1:100, function(i) sample(c(0,1), size = nrow(Grid), replace = T))

## Functions #################
## Triple For loop
getRects          <- function(trimtonOut, Grid){
  len1 <- dim(trimtonOut)[2]
  childli = childnew = rectidli = vector("list", len1);
  for (i in 1:len1) {
    childli[[i]] <- trimtonOut[,i]
  }
  for (u in 1:len1){
    rectidli[[u]] <- which(childli[[u]]==1, arr.ind = T)
  }
  for (z in 1:len1) {
    childnew[[z]] <- Grid[rectidli[[z]],];
  }
  return(childnew)
}
## Shortest Lapply
getRects1          <- function(trimtonOut, Grid){
  lapply(1:dim(trimtonOut)[2], function(i) {
    Grid[which(trimtonOut[,i]==1, arr.ind = T),]
  })
}
## Shorter Lapply
getRects2          <- function(trimtonOut, Grid){
  lapply(1:dim(trimtonOut)[2], function(i) {
    tmp = which(trimtonOut[,i]==1, arr.ind = T)
    Grid[tmp,]
  })
}
## Longest Lapply
getRects3          <- function(trimtonOut, Grid){
  lapply(1:dim(trimtonOut)[2], function(i) {
    tmp = trimtonOut[,i]
    tmp1 = which(tmp==1, arr.ind = T)
    Grid[tmp1,]
  })
}


## Execute and Compare #################
getRectV  <- getRects(mut2, Grid)
getRectV1 <- getRects1(mut2, Grid)
getRectV2 <- getRects2(mut2, Grid)
getRectV3 <- getRects3(mut2, Grid)

identical(getRectV,getRectV1)
identical(getRectV,getRectV2)
identical(getRectV,getRectV3)

## Benchmark #################
library(microbenchmark)
# mut2 = sapply(1:400, function(i) sample(c(0,1), size = nrow(Grid), replace = T))
mc = microbenchmark(
                    loop = getRects(mut2, Grid),
                    lap1 = getRects1(mut2, Grid),
                    lap2 = getRects2(mut2, Grid),
                    lap3 = getRects3(mut2, Grid)
)
mc
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those time differences are that significant?

```r
library(microbenchmark)
# mut2 = sapply(1:400, function(i) sample(c(0,1), size = nrow(Grid), replace = T))
mc = microbenchmark(
  loop = getRects(mut2, Grid),
  lap1 = getRects1(mut2, Grid),
  lap2 = getRects2(mut2, Grid),
  lap3 = getRects3(mut2, Grid)
)
mc
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>  loop 2.651485 2.699166 3.195301 2.756171 3.136741  8.010173   100
#>  lap1 2.755571 2.828128 3.098850 2.877806 3.012487  7.427598   100
#>  lap2 2.737105 2.808924 3.118260 2.863221 2.939996 13.706736   100
#>  lap3 2.719101 2.787040 3.191893 2.852963 3.004811  8.490867   100
```

Comment: They are not significant. You can also increase `mut2` by uncommenting the line before microbenchmark and you will see that the triple for-loop is always the "winner" and the difference increases. Although it might not be significant, I am trying to understand why, as it doesnt seem logical to me.

Comment: If the algorithmic complexity is the same then you will be seeing tiny differences related to some function calling overhead... Can you be more explicit about what seems not logical to you?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the *apply functions are always praised higher than a for loop. Well, I have to create 3 lists with the same length and fill them with 3 separate loops, instead of just creating 1 list with 1 lapply call.

Comment: From Advanced R by Hadley Wickham: *A common use of functionals is as an alternative to for loops. For loops have a bad rap in R. They have a reputation for being slow (although that reputation is only partly true, see modification in place for more details). But the real downside of for loops is that they’re not very expressive.* In your case the advantage of your `lapply` is expressiveness at almost the same speed as the explicit loop versions. That should be a good reason in itself.